# How does ethereum bypass the NAT

Tags: security, network, clients, peers

I wonder, since Ethereum is based on a decentralized p2p network, how does it get through the NAT Firewall? There is no server Ethereum can connect on, so there has to be a way for nodes to accept incoming connections. How does Ethereum do that?

Thanks in advance,
rpanic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now AFAICT it basically does not. I might be wrong but I think the network health is relying on several things:

- UPnP if it's available, to automatically forward the port to listen on
- Churn in the list of endpoints in the DHT, so old endpoints are dropped shortly after the ephemeral mapping goes.
- Nodes hosted with ports forwarded or in DMZ etc.

Otherwise I don't think NAT is handled explicitly.

Comment: Well that basically answers my question. I think with this 3 methods a network can indeed function reliable. Thank you :)

Comment: @RPanic I think it *can* yes, but if it actually does, well I am researching that..

Answer (score 1):

RPC's (request–response protocol) and ports. Common parity port for the network is 30303 and RPC will have a different port.

Comment: Does that mean you have to configure port forwarding?